# Puzzling rectangles

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, geometry, no-computers

Can you find two unequal rectangles whose areas add to $5\sqrt5$?

No computer solutions please.

Comment: Any restrictions on side length? Otherwise this seems trivial...

Comment: Is this homework? Voting to close as strictly a math question.

Comment: Also, use the [tag:no-computers] tag to specify no computer solutions.

Comment: Please close the question. Thank you. Vasslis

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, a 1×4√5 rectangle and a 1×√5 rectangle.